HsqlDb : how to make sure that data is really written to disk and crash resistant?
I have a java EE web application running under Tomee.
HsqlServer as well as the clint code is running within the same Java EE web application.
Everything is running fine.
But when the server crashes, I regularly lose weeks of the latest hsql database changes.
The sql changes are visible through hsqldb, because if I connect to the hsqldb server with an external sql tool, I can see my new data.
But as soon as the server is terminated abnormally, hsqldb does lose data.
I already issue regularly "checkpoint" commands. But that doesn't fix the problem.
Is there any other command that will really write all changes to disk in a crash resistant way ?
thank you!

If what you describe is accurate, then you should throw out your database server and choose a different one.  It should not be possible to lose data once committed.  Real database servers do page management very carefully to ensure that the data is always consistent.

It is possible to disable HSQLDB's settings for data persistence, but by default it does persist the data and a WRITE DELAY setting of zero persists at each commit.

Dear Tim: I must and want to stick with Hsqldb. I am sure that it is a problem on my side. But thank you for your comment

I found out that I had
SET FILES LOG FALSE

I guess that this is the reason for the data losses that I had.
I now use
  SET FILES LOG TRUE

(What I do not understand: According to the docs, a "checkpoint" operation should write all changes to disk even with logs disabled. And this does not work...)
Thank you !

By default HSQLDB writes the data to disk at regular intervals. Check the settings on your server's database URL settings for any properties that you may have changed. Also check SET FILES ... commands at the top of the .script file of the database for such changes. Read  http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/deployment-chapt.html#dec_tweaking and the Properties Chapter of the Guide http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_db_file_mem

Another observation: When I do a
"backup database to '/path/' not blocking"
then not all recent data is saved in the backup.
I must use a "blocking" backup to save all data.
Does that give an additional hint?

With SET FILES LOG TRUE setting, not blocking backs up to the exact point the command was issued.
